# RRDtool bad format problem

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I'm using RRDtool for graphing some monitoring information. One problem I faced when using rrd is using `GRPINT` directive. I use following command to graph networking Rx/Tx data:

```
rrdtool graph out.png -v bytes -a PNG --start "-6 hour" --title "WLAN traffic" \
    --vertical-label="Bit/s" \
    'DEF:_rx=/root/ppp0.rrd:rx:AVERAGE' \
    'DEF:_tx=/root/ppp0.rrd:tx:AVERAGE' \
    'CDEF:tx=_tx,-8,*' \
    'CDEF:rx=_rx,8,*' \
    'COMMENT:WLAN traffic\j' \
    "AREA:rx#333333:WLAN Rx" \
    "AREA:tx#990000:WLAN Tx" \
    'GPRINT:rx:AVERAGE:"Rx average - %d"' \
    'GPRINT:tx:AVERAGE:"Tx average - %d"'
```

I've got:

```
ERROR: bad format for GPRINT in 'Rx average - %d'
```

I tried to simplify format, but when I've got:

```
ERROR: bad format for GPRINT in '%d'
```

I understand that I doing something completely wrong. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `%d` format is for integers. `GPRINT` (and `PRINT`) only support double formats ... see `man sprintf` for inspiration. Try `%.0lf` for starters.